# JUnit testing of a class that uses Activity Reference

Tags: java, android, android-activity, junit

I have have a plain Java class in an Android apk as follows:

```
public class AdjustResizeWorkaround {
    public static void assistActivity (Activity activity) {
        new AdjustResizeWorkaround(activity);
    }

......
}
```

and

```
private AdjustResizeWorkaround(Activity activity) {
....
}
```

I want to do the unit testing of above class but when I use `AndroidTestCase` I can't get an Activity reference in JUnit. How can I get an Activity reference in JUnit?

As this class does not extends activity I cant use `ActivityInstrumentattionTestCase` in JUnit.

How to get an Activity reference?

Comment: Do those methods need the `Activity`? It's generally bad practice to pass the `Activity` around unless you need it. If you can change it to `Context` then you can use the `ApplicationContext` of the Test Application.

Comment: yes they need Activity. Is there any way to check that class? We are passing Activity reference in constructor and methods also.

Comment: Okay, keep in mind that is a *potential* memory leak. You should probably use a weak or soft reference instead of a hard reference. An Activity is like any other class, you can simple go `new Activity()` and that might work for you. Otherwise look into some of the Mocking frameworks.

Comment: Have you thought of using mocks?

Comment: I have no idea about mocking. Can u please tell me in detail how to use it.

Comment: @NikhilKumar Mocking is a large subject area, although relatively simple to get up and running with. I suggest you Google it and do a bit of research. You won't get much help here in comment/answer form.